# Use ruby array for a javascript array in erb. Escaping quotes

Tags: ruby, erb

i've found numerous things online for this but they dont work for me. am i missing something.

In my controller i have

```
@t = ["a","b","c"]
```

in the erb file that is 'callback' the @t renders like so:

```
[&quot;a&quot;, &quot;b&quot;, &quot;c&quot;]
```

i've done hacks to replace the " to proper `'` symbols. I've read that to_json should work but it doesnt.  The following does not work `["a","b","c"].to_json`.  The results are the same.

Comment: What are you expecting to see? That looks pretty good to me honestly...

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to see rendered?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`to_json` is working fine. What you're running into is Rails 3.x's XSS protection. There's a good article on this at [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3)/[ASCIIcasts](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3). The gist, though, is that you need to use the [`raw`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw) or `html_safe` methods:

In your controller:

```
@t_json = @t.to_json.html_safe
```

OR in your view:

```
<%= raw @t %>
```

Comment: I was getting a type error about html_safe getting json, but expecting data.  The `raw` worked for me though.  Thanks!